# WatchKit : error while communicating with the phone app

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am trying to communicate with the iPhone app. On the Watch Controller I have the following code:

```
 func requestDataFromPhone(messageText: String) {
        var infoDictionary = Dictionary<String,String>()
        infoDictionary["GetAppointmentString"] = "message"
        WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(infoDictionary) {
            (replyDictionary, error) -> Void in
            println("we made it!")
            if let castedResponseDictionary = replyDictionary as? [String: String],
                responseMessage = castedResponseDictionary["message"]
            {
                println(responseMessage)
                self.appointmentString.setText(responseMessage)
            }
        }
    }
```

On the AppDelegate of the iPhone app , I have this code :

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

        let response = "Appointment at noon tomorrow"
        let responseDictionary = ["message" : response]
        if let infoDictionary = userInfo as? [String: String],
            message = infoDictionary["GetAppointmentString"]
        {
             reply(responseDictionary)
        }
        reply(responseDictionary)
    }
```

I am always getting the following error :

> "Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 \"The
>   UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in
>   -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]\"
>   UserInfo=0x60800006b580 {NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in
>   -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]}"

What am I missing here ? Any pointers would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Why reply(responseDictionary) has been done twice ? Any specific purpose.

Comment: Even though the there is no message object, I still want to send the reply.

Comment: Does this happen everytime or only on the first time when the Application on the phone has not been launched? I've run into issues before where the first call to a "sleeping" application automatically just fails with that error. I've had to make a dummy call at app launch to mitigate it.

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was due to the app crashing while launching due to the fact that a library I was using was not listed under Embedded Binaries.